# Background Color on Absolutely Positioned <ul> Not Displaying

Tags: html, css, css-position, background-color, html-lists

I have a weird problem with a list that I'm trying to wrap vertically.  The alignment seems to be working, but I have several absolutely-positioned 'li's inside of a relatively-positioned 'div'.  The problem is that the 'li's seem to be displaying outside of the 'div'.  When I set the background-color of the 'div', nothing displays.  When I set the height and width of the 'div' explicitly, it appears overlapping the 'li's.  Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dt>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Team 422 | Mech Tech Dragons</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/william/Documents/Team422Site/template/css/standardLayout.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="mainContent">
                    <div class="footer">
                        <div class="socialBadges">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contactInfo">
                        </div>
                        <div class="sponsors">
                        </div>
                        <div class="siteMap">
                            <ul class="siteMapLevel1">
                                <li class="siteMapLevel1 siteMapCol1">About</li>
                                <li class="siteMapLevel1 siteMapCol2">Team 
                                    <br />
                                    <ul class="siteMapLevel2">
                                        <li class="siteMapLevel2">Organization</li>
                                        <li class="siteMapLevel2">Members</li>
                                        <li class="siteMapLevel2">Documents</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="siteMapLevel1 siteMapCol3">Competition
                                    <br />
                                    <ul class="siteMapLevel2">
                                        <li class="siteMapLevel2">Awards</li>
                                        <li class="siteMapLevel2">Robots
                                            <br />
                                            <ul class="siteMapLevel3">
                                                <li class="siteMapLevel3">Current</li>
                                                <li class="siteMapLevel3">History</li>
                                                <li class="siteMapLevel3">Manual</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="siteMapLevel2">The Game
                                            <br />
                                            <ul class="siteMapLevel3">
                                                <li class="siteMapLevel3">Overview</li>
                                                <li class="siteMapLevel3">Rules</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="siteMapLevel2">Scouting</li>
                                        <li class="siteMapLevel2">Safety</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="siteMapLevel1 siteMapCol4">Outreach 
                                    <br />
                                    <ul class="siteMapLevel2">
                                        <li class="siteMapLevel2">FLL</li>
                                        <li class="siteMapLevel2">Service</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="siteMapLevel1 siteMapCol5">Members</li> 
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my css:

```
body {
    background:#ffffff url('../../template/images/background.png') scroll no-repeat right top;
    font-family:ariel;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -moz-background-size: 650px 100%;
    border-left:15px solid #007200;
    border-right:15px solid #007200;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    padding-top:5px;
    min-width:925px;
}

.main {
    height:100%;
}

.content {
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-right:30px;
}

.footer{
    position:relative;
}

.siteMap {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}

.siteMapCol1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
}

.siteMapCol2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:150px;
}

.siteMapCol3 {
    position:absolute;
    left:300px;
}

.siteMapCol4 {
    position:absolute;
    left:450px;
}

.siteMapCol5 {
    position:absolute;
    left:600px;
}

.siteMapLevel1 {
    font-weight:bold;
    list-style-type:none;
    color:#333333;
    text-indent:none;
}

.siteMapLevel2 {
    font-weight:normal;
    list-style-type:none;
    color:#555555;
    padding-left:0px;
}

.siteMapLevel3 {
    list-style-type:none;
    color:#555555;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

I am displaying on a 1024x768 screen using Firefox 3.6.15

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely positioned elements arent going to expand their containing elements, only `realtive` and `static` positioned ones will. Therefore if you dont set a height/width the dimensions of `div.sitemap` and the `ul` are effectively 0.

Since you are hard coding positioning anyhow you might as well just switch to floats and hardcode the width and margin/padding instead. That way as long as you clear your floats they will expand the containing elements.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kMudG/

Answer (score 1):

rather than absolutely positioning the lists which is completely removing the lists from the flow, which is the reason why there's no background.. as **@prodigitalson** said in their answer (+1)

another alternative solution;

you could use `inline-block`s with a width of 150px keeping them in the positions you have set.. this way maybe has a slight advantage over floating them in that they won't wrap and you don't have to clear them

**Example JSFiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/BMVnr/)**

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure what you are asking, but you mentioned that your items are overflowing the div. In the css set overlow:hidden; and it might solve it. (If that is your problem)

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and it made a thin empty block the color of my background appear above where the absolutely-positioned 'li's were, but the 'li's disappeared.